# Having issue typing in text in textbox using Selenium Webdriver sendkeys

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am having an issue with typing text in a textbox using Selenium Webdriver.

I do the following:

```
                    element.clear();
            element.click();
            element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
            element.sendKeys("Joe");
```

and it types in "Joe", but it is grayed out, meaning it just clears the default value, and types instead of clicking on the textbox, and then typing it. When I manually type in "Joe", I click on the textbox so that the cursor is in the textbox, but element.click() does not do this for me.

Can anyone please suggest me a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this? You shouldn't have to click and backspace.

```
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("Joe");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
`new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.SendKeys(element, "Your Text").Build().Perform();
```